# How to get non inherited PHP class methods?

Tags: php, inheritance, reflection, phalcon

I would like to get non inherited child class public methods. I tried using Reflection Api like this:

```
$class = new \ReflectionClass($model);
$modelMethods = $class->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
$exclude = ['getSource', 'upsert', 'getUniqueKeyAttributes', 'beforeSave', 'columnMap', 'initialize', 'setId', 'getId'];
$CLASS = __CLASS__;

$props = array_filter(array_map(function(\ReflectionMethod $method) use ($exclude, $CLASS) {
    if($method->class === $CLASS && !in_array($method->name, $exclude)) {
        if(strpos($method->name, 'get') === 0) {
            return str_replace('get', '', $method->name);
        }
    }
}, $props));
```

But this makes a lot of redundant logic. I have to get all getters or setters automatically because I got more than 60 of them!

Comment: 60 getters/setters ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Sticking with existing solution

I would just replace `array_filter` with `array_map` for more efficient filtering internal. Declaring type of function parameter when you're controlling it 100% is not necessary, but slows PHP. Also `substr()` should appear faster than `str_replace()`.

Let me support an short example of quite the same but yet-different code:

```
    $class = 'Application\Entity\ExamplePhalconModel';

    // ure filtering those with "get" only
    $exclude = array_flip(['getSource', 'getId']);
    
    $result = array_map(function($v) { return substr($v->name, 3); } , array_filter((new \ReflectionClass($class))->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC), function ($v) use ($class, $exclude) {
        return (strpos($v->name, 'get') === 0 && $v->class === $class) && !array_key_exists($v->name, $exclude);
    }));
```

**Breaking it down**, firstly I'm creating an Reflection of class being inspected with `(new \ReflectionClass($class))->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC)` as you did. Putting this as first parameter to `array_filter()` allows me to ommit some variables declarations. As second parameter, just an `if` in function:

```
function ($v) use ($class, $exclude) {
    return (strpos($v->name, 'get') === 0 && $v->class === $class) && !array_key_exists($v->name, $exclude);
}
```

for inspecting if it starts with "get" at all, if it is in proper class and lastly, if it is not in exluded method names.

At last, whole `array_filter()` result wents to `array_map()` just to morph them from objects to strings not containing "get" word;

---

PS: Mostly an optimisation and obfuscation even further ;)

## 2. Phalcon Model::columnMap

Or just:

```
$props = array_map(function($str) {
        return \Phalcon\Text::camelize($str);
    }, array_values(Application\Entity\ExamplePhalconModel::columnMap()));
```

but you may need to filter-out an 'Id' field;